# Tag merge - uk and united-kingdom

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We appear to currently have two tags for the United Kingdom - [uk](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) and [united-kingdom](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

Based on [What version of country names should we use?](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-version-of-country-names-should-we-use) and the Travel.SE model, I'd suggest we make [uk](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) the main one, and merge [united-kingdom](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) into it.

Comment: Will do this later if no compelling objections (and I think we're pretty settled there)

Comment: Checking the other meta discussion and meta discussions on Travel.SE I couldn't find anything definite about which should be the main one (apart from the fact that Travel.SE is using uk). I added three answers that can be edited/up/downvoted based on preference

Answer (score 5):

Use [united-kingdom](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) as the main tag

Pros:

- At the moment it's more used than the [uk](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) tag (26 vs 15)
- Having the longer tag as main one is better for SEO

Cons:

- The country and citizenship tags will look different ([uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens) vs [united-kingdom](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom))

Answer (score 3):

Use [uk](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) as the main tag

Pros:

- It's what used on Travel.SE (for the UK at least)
- It's more in line with [uk-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-citizens)

Cons:

- We are not really using abbreviations elsewhere (except for [eu](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) and [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa))

Answer (score -2):

Use [gb](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gb) as the main tag

Pros:

- it's the actual ISO code of the country

Cons:

- it's not even used at the moment

Comment: Almost no-one thinks of GB as the code, and you'd then have to add a tag for Northern Ireland which would make things confusing (GB = Great Britain, UK = United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)

Comment: I know, but still officially `GB` is the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code for the country and not `UK` (although the latter is reserved)

Comment: Country code for domains is `.uk`, and that's what most people think of. GB = United Kingdom makes no sense, no matter what some ISO-wonk might say...