# Tag merge request: 'usa' and 'united-states'

Tags: support, tags

There are both [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [united-states](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tags. I'm not sure which one should end up being the primary one, because [Tag merge - uk and united-kingdom](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/103/150) indicates it should be [united-states](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) but that's the lesser used tag at the moment.

Comment: You could potentially create a poll as well for people to decide

Comment: Defs in favor. If we go by Travel SE, there united states is mapped to usa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to have been forgotten back then. I checked, and it looks like people used the `usa` tag more often (1000 vs 100), so `united-states` was merged into `usa`.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion was made almost three years ago, and it seems reasonable to me, but there's been no action. Is there any reason to continue to have both tags?